# Why earth ground connection does not leak current?

Tags: circuit-design, ground, grounding, theory

This seems like a question which has been asked multiple times on forums. I researched the problem but I still was unable to figure out the answer which I can at least intuitively understand. ***So in this simple circuit why is there no current leakage to earth?*** Assume that it is a true earth ground connection (a rod in the earth for example).

Update: I am giving researched answers below, but not as the only options. I am not satisfied with any of them, and give my explanation as to why. So I am hoping for either an elaboration or an alternative answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjOHZA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The answers I have found:-

1. [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148675/when-does-and-when-doesnt-current-flow-to-ground) **With only one connection to ground there is no circuit for the current to flow through. It can't flow "to" ground, because there is nowhere for it to flow to. There's no difference between ground and a wire dangling in the breeze.** However for current to flow there must be potential difference. And because the ground and the battery return has the same potential - why would current prefer to flow specifically to the return point. Especially taken into account that earth can absorb all electrons generated by the battery (on contrary for example to just piece of wire).
2. [Here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36516/since-neutral-is-connected-to-ground-how-is-current-kept-off-of-ground) **The ground isn't a great conductor and while it is in parallel with the service, the amount of current returning through the ground is so small it is effectively zero** - Firstly this answer implies that there's some leakage occurs which just depends on earth resistance. Also I do not understand which resistance is taken into account. Where it is measured? I think also the answer relates to the several connection of the circuit to the ground.

So anyone can give real physical explanation of this?

Comment: 1) If there is a potential difference, it is equalized instantly after the connection. So yeah, there would be an instantaneous current. 2) I think it is not an answer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The question why would it stop then. The current flow can take either path to the ground or to the return.Both with the same potential. Why the second one is preferred?

Comment: 2) is an is more applicable to the AC mains situation where there can be some leakage and/or capacitive coupling to ground causing small (AC!) currents to flow. But your example is DC so 2) simply does not apply.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie So what is the correct answer?

Comment: I say that 2 does not apply so.....

Comment: Ground and return are *the same point*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If they are the same why current does not flow to the ground.

Comment: Let's turn that around, why **would** the current flow into the ground? What would happen if it did? How would you make that current flow into ground? Would there be a stream of electrons going from the circuit into the ground? Is that sustainable?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It will just flow there. Partially (half of the current) to the return to keep the battery working and partially (another half) to the ground.

Comment: The current will flow only between points having a potential difference. In order to *maintain* a potential difference over time you need a closed circuit. If you have a potential difference in open circuit, it will get equalized after short time. That's it. The path to ground is open. the path to battery is closed.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Electron reaching the ground connection does not know which direction the circuit is closed or open. It flows to the lowest potentials. Both paths have the same potential.

Comment: *It will just flow there. Partially (half of the current) to the return to keep the battery working and partially (another half) to the ground.* That is really not true. Current flows in loops and cannot split halfway to somewhere else without returning.

Comment: But if the electron chooses ground then the ground gets negatively charged making it **harder** for the electron to go there. So it will not.

Comment: @Boris Yes. Now consider the electron is "choosing" the wrong path and going to the ground. Now the potential of ground have changed! So the next electron will go the other way, until the potentials are equal again.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The whole idea of the ground is that it cannot become charged.

Comment: @Boris It's relative. So it's the circuit is getting "uncharged" (or "discharged?) if you like

Comment: *The whole idea of the ground is that it cannot become charged* **Nonsense**, if I charge a metal object the ground gets discharged. The **total** sum of charge must remain constant.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_(electricity) a "ground" is usually idealized as an infinite source or sink for charge, which can absorb an unlimited amount of current without changing its potential

Comment: *current without changing its potential* That is correct and I'm correct as well, why is that? Because the earth is much much larger than my object so on the whole earth the charge displacement makes little difference but it does on my small object.

Comment: Anyway. Let's go back to our favorite water-and-pipes analogy. Consider battery as a pump and the ground as a reservoir with a very high(or low, or whatever) water pressure. will connecting the closed pipe/pump circuit cause any water flow to/from that reservoir?

Comment: *which can absorb an unlimited amount of current without changing its potential* And where does this charge come from? Is it made somewhere? Nope, charge is an electron taken away from it's atom or an Atom from which an electron has been taken away (Ion).

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? My answer assumes you have the circuit as drawn.  The one from @Trevor recognises that in the real world there are parasitic components that are not shown on the circuit diagram.  Both are correct if you take them in the sense intended. Please explain where you need further clarification.

Comment: @Boris You are right. There is a leakage of electrons flowing out of your circuit due to the random movement of electrons; however, this is being cancelled by the same number of electrons flowing _into_ your circuit as well. There is no current because there is no _net_ flow of electrons due to the earth and the negative battery terminal being at the same voltage potential.

Comment: @jstarr why would electrons return? There's an EMF pushing charges down the wire from + to -. The questions is why it is pushing it to the return and not to the ground. Both paths are at the same potential

Comment: @Boris, no they are not at the same potential, and even if they were, the bottom of the battery is negative with respect to the top and  the electrons move around the circuit from the bottom to the top. No extra electrons are added or removed from the circuit, as would be the case if something crossed the ground connection.

Comment: Must be a lot of bent pennies in here.. none of them seem to be dropping.. That tells me the OP has some basic concept wrong in his head that wont be answered till we know what it is.

Comment: The question "2" is about when you have **two** ground connections.

Answer (score 4):

In reality there is current in the ground connection, but not enough to measure above ambient noise level.

Below is your equivalent circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff8Sew.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**ADDITION**

As such we normally ignore that leakage current in DC circuits. So let us look at your question another way.

For the moment consider what would happen if an electron fell down that "drain" to ground. What happens to the rest of the circuit?

Suddenly it will have a missing electron and will have a net positive charge. 
The ground now has an extra electron and has net negative charge. That means there is a reverse voltage on the ground wire which will immediately cause the electron to return to the circuit.

The opposite would happen if somehow an extra electron were to arrive from the ground. The circuit would be at a negative potential and ground would be positive. The visiting electron would be immediately repelled.

In actuality, that returning force is what prevents the electrons from crossing the connection in the first place. It is a self stabilizing state.

Comment: Hmmm - I'm not sure about the precision of your 1e16 resistor ...

Comment: @Trevor Air resistance? And if the circuit is enclosed in vacuum?  And only ground wire is "piercing" the vacuum chamber.

Comment: @brhans ya that was a very rough approximate and will vary widely... it's the exponent that is important though .. huge # = b.all current ;) Things change a lot when its a high frequency voltage source though.

Comment: @Boris indeed, in a vacuum you still have an impedance.. but it gets complicated.

Comment: @Boris, the point is you need a loop back to a higher potential  for current to flow through that wire. Now you will get a loop, be that through leakage in air or the impedance of a vaccum, but the current that will flow round that loop is so small you can take it as zero for a DC circuit. A high frequency power source though would be different.

Comment: @Trevor I think for current to flow there must be a potential difference. period. The loop is need by any reasonable EMF generating device to sustain this potential difference.

Comment: @Boris that is correct, for current to flow, you need two things, a loop and a potential difference.

Comment: I'm still not seeing a ground current here. As \$R_{air}\$ is in parallel with \$R_2\$ so there is no current in the earth. If it were the case that you had two separate ground connections then some current might flow out of one but it would be flowing back into the other as the current out of the battery would also have to flow into it to avoid breaking Kirchhoff's current law.

Comment: @WarrenHill it does not matter. The leakage resistance from the top of the battery through air and back through ground to the bottom of the battery exists. It may be negligible, but it is still there. Kirchoffs laws still hold.

Comment: @Trevor I know I'm being pedantic here but this is only true if there are separate grounds the voltage from the top of the battery finds a path to ground via the air. Agreeably this is negligible and the ground as \$R_{air}\$ is very large. This ground connection is not necessarily intended it may be, for example the earthed case of a nearby computer. but this current has to be returning through the the intentional ground connection, or via another route to ensure we don't break KCL. Current out of the battery must equal its return current.

Comment: @Trevor I would accept your answer know as with two connections there is an an alternative return path

Comment: @WarrenHill yes indeed there are a myriad of high impedance paths. But since the OP is specifically asking about current in his hard connection to ground, it's the only one I want to mention here. and yes, in reality, top of battery back to that wire will have taken numerous routes to get there a few of which come up that ground link.. but that is not pertinent to the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is explained by [Kirchhoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws). He has two laws: the voltage law and the current law.

I won't explain the voltage law, as that is not what your question is asking, but the current law simply states:

> The sum of all currents into a node is zero

alternatively:

> The sum of all currents out of a node is zero

What this means in the case of your simple circuit is that the current \$I_1\$ flowing out of the top of your battery is equal to to the current \$I_2\$ flowing into the battery.

Since the battery and resistor are in series with the resistor, then the current flowing into the bottom node via the resistor is \$I_1\$.

Let's call the current flowing to earth \$I_3\$.

\$I_3 = I_1 - I_2 = 0 \$ since \$I_1\$ = \$I_2\$.

Comment: Not sure Kirchhoff is applicable here as adding earth connection breaks the assumption of "Lumped element model" Kirchhoff  is applicable to. Especially the second assumption about the constant charge as earth effectively makes the charge "dissapear" from the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

In the circuit from your question, the earth ground connection function is of a reference point, i.e. a zero potential point. From this point, you can specify all voltages in circuit nodes. It's a convenience for the analysis, say, nodal method.

There isn't relation with current. Is a convention to assign a node as a zero-potential node.

Comment: i specifically mentioned that it is not reference point. But real ground connection.

Answer (score 0):

> So in this simple circuit why is there no current leakage to earth?
>   Assume that it is a true earth ground connection (a rod in the earth
>   for example).

The circuit diagram shows no elements that would cause a current to flow
to ground.   If current DOES flow to the 'earth ground' node,
is it positive?  Negative?  AC? DC?

Simply put, this circuit doesn't create any current output, unless 
other circuit elements exist, which are not shown.   If there's a storm 
cloud, and lightning strikes, there WILL be current to ground.  That,
however, isn't part of the schematic, so isn't part of the equation.
Thus, we're left with 'zero' current predicted.